What yield curve to use for FX Options in BSM?
Picking the correct r and q for BSM is somehow critical as O/N rates might differ from Govt Bond rates dramatically. My question is quite straight-forward:
What is the best practice of using interest rates in the BS model for an FX option, say EURUSD, which expires in 1 year? Is it 1yr USD-EUR yields on Govt Bonds, or, 1y implied rates of SOFR and EONIA, or any other O/N indexed rates?

Sofr/estr. You should probably xccy adjust the estr rate you use (I.e. imply from fx swaps)

for sure, include the cross-currency basis.

what adjustment do you suggest? @user68819

could you elaborate? @DimitriVulis

Cross currency adjustment as @DimitriVulis suggested

If you read some book that is only a few decades old, the book will say that covered interest parity (CIP) must hold, but later, in practice, CIP doesn't exactly hold. When pricing fx forwards, options, etc, do not omit this adjustment for CIP's  market-observable failure to hold. Here is an example paper explaining the cross-currency basis https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt1609e.pdf , there many other good papers.

Not duplicate, but related question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53410

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63661/54838 shows how to imply a rate. This approach is consistent with Bloomberg an will match OVML exactly, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70296/54838. Definitely not government bond yields, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74098/54838

Thanks for the excellent recommendations, will read them all.
